# F# pattern matching oddity

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

Consider the following nonsense lambda:

```
function
| [] -> "Empty list"
| hd::tl -> "Not so empty list"
```

This works fine. Now I rewrite it as follows:

```
function
| [] -> "Empty list"
| hd::tl & l -> "Not so empty list"
```

Again, for nonsense reasons (and I know that I can achieve the same effect by using `as` instead of `&`, but this all has to do with a code-golf problem that's not pertinent to this question). Now the F# compiler tells me:

> warning FS0025: Incomplete pattern matches on this expression. For
>   example, the value '[]' may indicate a case not covered by the
>   pattern(s).

This doesn't make any sense - I am explicitly handling the case of `[]` in the first rule. I don't see what changed from the first function to the second with respect to `[]`; neither function's second rule would have matched it yet only the second function gives the warning. All I did was add an additional pattern that matches *anything*.

Of course, invoking the second function with an empty list does succeed.

Is there a valid reason why this warning occurred, or does the F# pattern validation simply have some quirks? I could see having some cases like this when more advanced patterns are employed, but this seems like a pretty basic one. Even if the problem can't be solved generally, it seems like this type of case would be common enough to merit special handling in the compiler.

Comment: i've never seen `&` used in that way.  Can you link to some documentation on what that does?

Comment: @JaredPar - see AND pattern here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547125.aspx.  Basically it means you can get head, tail and the entire list in one go

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think F# compiler is being practical in this case.

In the end, the second rule can be expressed as a constraint on input list `xs`:

```
xs = hd :: tl && xs = l
```

F# compiler doesn't seem to explore `&&` constraints. This is reasonable because constraints can be arbitrarily complex and the use of `&` is quite rare.

We have a similar problem with [partial active patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233248.aspx):

```
let (|Empty|_|) = function
    | [] -> Some()
    | _ -> None

let (|NonEmpty|_|) = function
    | _ :: _ -> Some()
    | _ -> None

// warning FS0025
let f = function
    | Empty -> "Empty list"
    | NonEmpty -> "Not so empty list"
```

To fix this issue, you can:

- Use `as` instead of `&`, which is more appropriate since `l` is just a binding.
- Add a wildcard pattern to the end to eliminate the warning. I usually write

  ```
  let f =
      function
      | hd::tl & l -> "Not so empty list"
      | _ -> "Empty list"
  ```
- Suppress the warning using `nowarn "25"`.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen the warning with the partial active patterns before. That one actually makes sense though, seeing as active patterns are compiled functions and not macros and therefore the compiler can't statically verify the completeness of the matches. Now if there were some way to define an active pattern with the `inline` keyword (I've tried), that might be a different story.

Comment: You can use `inline` with active patterns: `let inline (|Empty|_|) xs = match xs with [] -> Some () | _ -> None`, but the warning is still there.

Comment: I guess you're right. Though if I do `<@@  function [] -> Some() | _ -> None  @@>` I see that the AST for the match expression is just an if/else, so the pattern information is still lost.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you found another case (aside from `when` clauses and partial active patterns) where the compiler's decision procedure is not powerful enough. (That's why the warning message says *may indicate* :-)).

If you wanted to get the same functionality without warnings, then you could use a complete active pattern like this (but in reality, for lists, I would probably just go with `_` for the empty list case as @pad suggests):

```
let (|Empty|NonEmpty|) l =
  match l with [] -> Empty | x::xs -> NonEmpty(x, xs, l)

let foo = function  
  | Empty -> 0
  | NonEmpty(x, xs, l) -> 1
```

Comment: It does say "may indicate," but it also says "incomplete" rather "possibly incomplete," so it is somewhat ambiguous.